# How this function is built?

Tags: real-analysis, gamma-function

[enter link description here](https://journalofinequalitiesandapplications.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s13660-018-1620-3)

in this link **"Sharp Smith’s bounds for the gamma function "**
I want to know with explain **(Theorem 2)** how that formula is got?

\begin{eqnarray*}
g(x)=\ln \Gamma(x+\frac{x}{2})-[\frac{x}{2}\ln(2\pi)+\frac{16}{21}x\ln x+\frac{5x}{42}(x^2+\frac{7}{20})-x-\frac{\sqrt(35)}{42}\operatorname{arccot}(\frac{\sqrt(20)}{7}x)]
\end{eqnarray*}
How this function is built?

Comment: @YuriyS theorem 2 in the paper and that i wrote in up ! how the author build it ?

Comment: Most likely they took the simple function from Lemma 1 and then integrated it

Comment: ok , but how he edit the relation between theorem 1 and integration of lemma 1,specially last part  (tanh x\2)

Comment: he integration lemma 1 and make relation between it and theorem 1  then he get theorem 2, how he get last part of theorem 2 (arccot x)

Comment: That's simply what we get by integrating $$\frac{4}{3} \frac{15x^{2}+4}{x ( 20x^{2}+7 ) }$$ twice. You can check yourself using wolframalpha.com

Comment: ohh, thanks for you @YuriyS